# $router.push não está funcionando no VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify, vue-router

Boa noite, estou iniciando os estudos em desenvolvimento web e escolhi o VueJS com o Vuetify pra começar. Logo de cara não estou conseguindo mudar de página ao clicar em um botão.
Eu instalei o vue-router pelo NPM e criei o arquivo router.js com o seguinte código:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import Dashboard from  './Dashboard.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'App',
    component: App
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
  }
]
})
```

Depois, importei esse arquivo no main.js:

```
new Vue({router,vuetify,render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#app')
```

No botão eu coloquei o seguinte código:

```
@click="$router.push('/dashboard')"
```

Ao clicar no botão, o endereço da URL é alterado corretamente, porém a página não muda para o componente Dashboard. No console, nenhum erro é mostrado. Eu procurei mas não consegui descobrir o problema. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou: `<v-btn to="/dashboard">DASHBOARD</v-btn>` ?

Comment: Se nenhuma das opções funcionar, tente: `this.$router.replace('/dashboard')`

Answer (score 0):

Para navegar entre paginas tens várias opções:

1) Usando `router-link`:

```
// Hardcoded Link
<router-link to="/dashboard">Go to Dashboard</router-link>

// Usando nome da rota
<router-link :to="{name: 'Dashboard'}">Go to Dashboard</router-link>
```

2) Navegação programática:

```
// literal string path
this.$router.push('dashboard')

// object
this.$router.push({ path: 'Dashboard' })
```

Finalmente não esquecer de usar `router-view` no componente de entrada, neste caso provavelmente em `App.vue`

```
// App.vue

<div>
 <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```